# Link in function of the position of the window/body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, scroll

If you check the jsFiddle I did, you can see a yellow div and a red one.

What I would do is that the first click on the yellow one make a scroll to an anchor, and a second (not double)  click still on the yellow div send me to a "true" link (like www.google.com)

In simple words I would use the same `a` tag, for scrolling and for hyperlink. 
Here is the  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k83hF/2/)

Comment: This should do: http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/k83hF/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add a global variable var firstclick=false;

```
var firstclick=false;
$j(".scroll").click(function(event){
    if(firstclick){
        window.location.href='google.com';
    }else{
        your code
        firstclick=true;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the classname like this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(".scroll,.scrolled").click(function (event) { //Add the "scrolled" class to the event listener
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($j(this).hasClass('scroll')) { //If there the "scroll" class
        //calculate destination place
        var dest = 0;
        if ($j(this.hash).offset().top > $j(document).height() - $j(window).height()) {
            dest = $j(document).height() - $j(window).height();
        } else {
            dest = $j(this.hash).offset().top;
        }
        //go to destination
        $j('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: dest
        }, 500, 'swing');
        $j(this).removeClass('scroll').addClass('scrolled'); //replaces the "scroll" class with "scrolled" class
    } else { 
        document.location.href = "http://www.google.de" //Redirect to URL
    } 
});
```